# Глаголы по виду

Tags: глаголы

Противопоставление глаголов по виду, как специфическое свойство славянских языков

Comment: Поподробнее, если можно.

Answer (score 4):

В русском, как и в других славянских  языках, имеется грамматическая категория вида, противопоставляющая два значения: «совершенный вид» и «несовершенный вид». Выражение этого противопоставления является для русского языка обязательным: всякий глагол, употребленный в высказывании на русском языке, обладает тем или иным значением категории вида, т.е. является глаголом либо совершенного, либо несовершенного вида.
     Это распространяется, в том числе, и на так  называемые двувидовые глаголы: в предложениях типа Я женюсь, где глагол может быть понят двояким образом – как глагол совершенного вида (будущего времени) и как глагол несовершенного вида (настоящего времени), имеет место грамматическая неоднозначность, порождаемая внешним совпадением (омонимией) разных грамматических форм.

При помощи категории вида в русском языке могут выражаться различные смысловые противопоставления, относящиеся      к понятийной категории вида. Принято говорить об общем значении  (семантическом инварианте) – каждого из видов, а также самого видового противопоставления – и о частных значениях видов (частновидовых  значениях).

Вид — глагольная категория, показывающая характер протекания действия во времени, выражающая отношение действия к его внутреннему пределу, результату. Категория вида присуща всем глаголам русского языка в любой форме.
     Глаголы совершенного вида отвечают на вопрос что сделать? и обозначают действие, ограниченное в своей длительности, имеющее внутренний предел, законченность. Глаголы совершенного вида могут обозначать действие, которое закончилось (или закончится), достигнув результата (выучить, нарисовать), действие, которое началось (или начнётся), причём само это начало действия понимается как его граница, предел (заиграть, запеть), однократное действие (толкнуть, крикнуть, прыгнуть — глаголы с суффиксом - ну).
     Глаголы несовершенного вида отвечают на вопрос что делать? и обозначают действие без указания  на его предел, без ограничения протекания его во времени, действие длительное или повторяющееся (учить, рисовать, играть, кричать).
    Глаголы несовершенного и совершенного вида образуют видовые пары. Видовую пару составляют глагол несовершенного вида и глагол совершенного вида, имеющие одинаковое лексическое значение и различающиеся только значением вида: читать — прочитать, писать — написать, строить — построить. Подробнее здесь:

- [Глагол](http://www.planetadruzey.com/art_view.php?id=260);
- [Лекционный материал - Морфология](http://gendocs.ru/v14050/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB_-_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_2);
- [Глагол в русском языке](http://www.e-ng.ru/literatura/glagol_v_russkom_yazyke.html).